# how can i update the images in my MVC 3 site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, image, pageload

i have Images in my MVC3-Webseite that they must be updates in every 30 Sec. Because the Images are updated im Server in every 30 Sec. So i have tried to update it with JQuery like :

```
<div id="galerie">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img id = "img1" class = "img1" alt="Image 7" src="@Url.Content("Content/Images/Image_7.jpg")"/>
            Image 7
        </li>
        <li>
            <img id = "img2" class = "img2" alt="Image 5" src="@Url.Content("Content/Images/Image_5.jpg")"/>
            Image 5
        </li>

</div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
     function UpdateImages() { 
         $.get('@Url.Action("Details","Display", new { id = "test" } )', function (data) {
             $('#main').replaceWith(data);
         }); 
     } 
    function myFunction() {
        setInterval(UpdateImages, 30000);
    }
</script>
```

But Problem is that the Images are not still updated. They need to Pageload again. don't that?
so i want to know how can i fire the Pageload event with JS? or is there any other solution for the Problem?
thank you

MarekBurkut

Comment: What you are getting in data? and how are you making image url in this data?

Comment: i am getting the whole site the proper contents. so i have replace it the "$('#main').replaceWith(data);" proper Page Fragments. The Image URLs are not changed. They are always same. that means the URLs are never changed. Only changes are the Image contents.

Answer (score 1):

If the URL of the images does not change, the browser will assume the images it has in cache as still the right ones.

Triggering a reload in JS is easy:

```
document.location.href = document.location.href;
```

Every change to the href property triggers a page reload, even if that value doesn't change.

To make sure the images are actually loaded from the server again, you may have to send appropriate Cache-Headers with them.

Alternatively, if you don't want the page to reload and just replace the images, you can append a random parameter to the image URL: `../image1.jpg?p=121799595` This will force the browser to query the server.

**Edit**: Or, you can pass the images through an MVC action to ensure you get a fresh copy every time:

```
public FileStreamResult StreamImage(string fileName)
{
  // todo: Check whether the file actually exists and is an image
  string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "images/";
  return File(new FileStream(path + fileName, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg", fileName);
}
```

Comment: i am sorry for my last comment. actuelly it has worked with the reload. i have not just seen it. thank your lens Neubauer

Comment: i have noticed now that it reloads the images only for same times f.e. max 10 times. then it dosn't work reliable. it means it reloads changed images randomly. i don't how can fix the cause of the randomly reloading of the changed images.

Comment: Are you sending any cache headers with the images? You may have to pass the images through an action instead of linking to static files.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery.get() is known to cache the data. consider using JQuery.ajax() instead and set cache: false. with .ajax(), you will have more control of your code.

```
function UpdateImages() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("Details","Display")',
        data: 'id=test',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('#main').replaceWith(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```